# Concatenate two spacy docs together?

Tags: nlp, spacy

How do I concatenate two spacy docs together? To merge them into one?

```py
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc1 = nlp(u'This is the doc number one.')
doc2 = nlp(u'And this is the doc number two.')
new_doc = doc1+doc2
```

Of course that will return an error as a doc object is not concatenable by default. Is there a straightforward solution to do that?

I looked at this:
https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2229
The issue seems closed so it sounds like they have implemented a solution but I cannot find a simple example of that being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```py
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import Doc

nlp = spacy.blank('en')
doc1 = nlp(u'This is the doc number one.')
doc2 = nlp(u'And this is the doc number two.')

# Will work for few Docs, but see further recommendations below
docs=[doc1, doc2]

# `c_doc` is your "merged" doc
c_doc = Doc.from_docs(docs)
print("Merged text: ", c_doc.text)

# Some quick checks: should not trigger any error.
assert len(list(c_doc.sents)) == len(docs)
assert [str(ent) for ent in c_doc.ents] == [str(ent) for doc in docs for ent in doc.ents]
```

For "a lot" of different sentences, it might be better to use [`nlp.pipe`](https://spacy.io/api/language#pipe) as shown in [the documentation](https://spacy.io/api/doc#from_docs).

Hope it helps.

Comment: You answered the question as it is. My real documents were more complicated than those examples and could not work ```AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.span.Span' object has no attribute 'user_data'```  so indeed I  had to use a NLP pipe in between, you pointed me to the right direction. Thank you!